# Go test file for specific OS or architecture

Tags: testing, go

In Go, filenames have semantic meaning. For example:

```
*_windows.go // Only include in compilations for Windows
*_unix.go    // Only include in compilations for Unix
*_386.go     // Only include in compilations for 386 systems
*_test.go    // Only include when run with `go test`
```

However, I can't seem to get the following to work:

```
*_windows_test.go // Only include when running `go test` on windows
*_test_windows.go // Another attempt
```

Is this even possible with Go? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Just use a [build constraint](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/) on the test files.

```
// +build windows
```

> A build constraint is evaluated as the OR of space-separated options; each option evaluates as the AND of its comma-separated terms; and each term is an alphanumeric word or, preceded by !, its negation. That is, the build constraint:

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid I might have to do that... oh well.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out I was wrong. It does work. The issue was that I also had a file called `foo_unix_test.go`, and apparently Go doesn't support the `*_unix.go` syntax as a special case.

Comment: I don't remember, sorry. This was a long time ago. Try them both and see which one works, I guess?